# Google App engine rest api from iOS

Tags: google-app-engine, rest

In I/O 2012 Google app engine video presentation, they presented a Rest Api release for iOS, Android.

Have anyone seen this, if so where?

Thanks
Regards
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your referring to the new endpoints facility.  Have a look at this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/UUu5Ztp6EPg

Its in trusted tester status at the moment.